# MS InfoPath: How do you populate a date box by using a function? Mostly a formatting date issue

Tags: infopath, infopath-2007

This might be a simple question. But I am trying to use a rule in an InfoPath field where if a user enters a certain value in a text box, a date box will populate with a certain date.

Example: User enters "Orange" in the Textbox1 field. Datefield1 should populate with 11/30/2010.

The problem is I have no idea how to setup/format the date in the rule box. [See picture for details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITHPb.jpg)

InfoPath marks the format as invalid. I've tried 2011-Nov-30, 30-Nov-2011, and a few more. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be the date format yyyy-mm-dd ("2010-01-01"). Alternatively you can use the date function `today()` if it is always going to be the current date.